# Outlook Macro to match domain name from a list in excel

Tags: vba, outlook

I need a macro which can match domain name of the email ids in TO and CC from a list of emails(preferably from excel) and if any of the email address does not match, it should throw a pop-up asking if the user wants to continue and if yes then the mail should be sent as it is and a email id should be added in BCC.

Please find the sample code, it works but I also want to compare the domain name as a sub-string in the subject.

Ex: The if the subject line is "ABC Report- Company1- Jan-2 and it is sent to a1@company1.com, a2@compay2.com then it should prompt that the a2@company2.com is an unauthorized email and ask if still the user want to proceed, if Yes it should copy admin@mycompany.com in BCC and delay the mail by 5mins.

```
            Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
            Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
            Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
            Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
            Dim prompt As String
            Dim strMsg As String
            Dim Address As String
            Dim lLen
            Dim strSubject As String

            Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

            strSubject = Item.Subject
            If strSubject Like "*ACB Report*" Or strSubject Like "*XYZ Report*" Then
               

            Set recips = Item.Recipients
            For Each recip In recips
            Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor

             Address = LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS))
            lLen = Len(Address) - InStrRev(Address, "@")

            Select Case Right(Address, lLen)
                Case "cdolive.com", "gmail.com", "slipstick.com", "outlookmvp.com"
                    
                Case Else ' remove case else line to be warned when sending to the addresses
                 strMsg = strMsg & " " & Address & vbNewLine
            End Select
            Next

            If strMsg <> "" Then
            prompt = "This email will be sent outside of the company to:" & vbNewLine & strMsg & vbNewLine & "Please check recipient address." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Do you still wish to send?"
            If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
            End If
            End If
            End If
            End Sub
```

Comment: Please share with us some concerns --  During the 5 min delay, where is the email?  In the user's Inbox? Can the user update it to remove the BCC??  In some other user folder where they can still access it?  Who can touch that delayed email?  Delay only if BCC added?

Comment: It should de in the sender's out box however, if the send try to remove bcc it should not trigger the mail to the original audience

Answer (score 0):

The next to last part of an email address is the Second Level Domain (2LD).
This seems to be finding Recipient2LD that is different from the Subject Company.

The Subject seems to be free form typing by users, and I have no idea how to parse the SubjectCompany out of the Subject line, but if you could then this could be added after EndSelect and before Next.

```
    Dim RecipDomainParts() As String 
    RecipDomainParts = Split(Right(Address, lLen), ".") 
    Dim Recip2LD As String  ' Recipient Second Level Domain
    Recip2LD = DomainParts(UBound(DomainParts) - 1)
    ' I have no idea how to parse the SubjectCompany out of the Subject line
    If Recip2LD <> SubjectCompany Then
        strMsg = strMsg & " " & Address & vbNewLine
    End If
```

->>added 9/2/18

you need to decide yourself the general outline of your process: whether to possibly have an error message for each Recipient for each problem (List or Subject) or to combine into one message for a Recipient, while doing each Recipient, or append each msg into one message at the end of all Recipients...  Then follow your outline.  Work at refining the outline first, then write the code to match.

It may be good to make sub for "Recip_in_List"  and make a sub for "RecipDomain_in_Subject" after you revise the outline.

BCC probably should not be skipped, as user might try to put an email there.
Your xyz@qwerty.com should be in the List.

variable SendMail cannot be set to True because it would wipe out False that had been set on prior Recipient.  By doing Exit Sub when vbNo you eliminate this boolean.

```
Set Delay = 0min
For each Recip 

    If Recip not in List
        Popup to user
        If vbNo then Cancel=True and exit without send
        Else add BCC of xyz@qwerty.com if not there
        endif
    endif

    If RecipDomain not in Subject
        Popup to user
        If vbNo then Cancel=True and exit without send
        Else add BCC of admin@qwerty.com if not there
             set Delay = 5min
        endif
    endif

Next Recip
SEND with Delay
```

Comment: Thanks @donPablo. I managed to get the code which works for my requirement.
However, I want to modify it, where in it should 1st check for a predefined substring in subject and also a predefined domain name with the domain in the recipients. If the domain(from recipient) does not match with the predefined domain, it should pop up error message with Yes & No. On yes it should sent out email should bcc a specific id on no Cancel=True. Have a look at my code and suggest.

Comment: @NiteshSingh  see additions above

Answer (score 0):

```
            Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
            Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
            Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
            Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
            Dim prompt As String
            Dim strMsg As String
            Dim Address As String
            Dim lLen
            Dim strSubject As String

            Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

            strSubject = Item.subject
            If strSubject Like "*ABC Report*" Or strSubject Like "*XYZ Report*" Then


            Set recips = Item.Recipients
            For Each recip In recips

             If recip.Type <> olBCC Then


                 Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor

                 Address = LCase(pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS))


                 'rlen = Len(Address) - InStrRev(Address, "@")
                 'If strSubject Like "*rlen*" Then

                 lLen = Len(Address) - InStrRev(Address, "@")

                 'Select Case Left(Address, rlen)
                    'Case "acceture", "slipstick"
                    'Case Else
                    'strMsg = strMsg & " " & Address & vbNewLine
                    'End Select
                    'Next

                Dim SendMail As Boolean
                 Select Case Right(Address, lLen)
                    Case "cdolive.com", "slipstick.com", "outlookmvp.com", "accenture.com"
                        ' "select case" is doing nothing in this case
                        SendMail = True
                    Case Else ' remove case else line to be warned when sending to the addresses
                        strMsg = strMsg & " " & Address & vbNewLine
                 End Select


                    If strMsg <> "" And Not SubjectContainsEmailDomain(strSubject, Address) Then
                        prompt = "The system has detected that you are sending this email to some unauthorized user:" & vbNewLine & strMsg & vbNewLine & "Please check recipient address." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Do you still wish to send?"
                        If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbExclamation + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
                            Cancel = True
                        Else
                            ' add BCC
                            Dim objRecip As Recipient

                            Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add("myid@gmail.com")
                            objRecip.Type = olBCC
                            objRecip.Resolve
                            'MailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateAdd("n", 90, Now)
                        End If
                    End If

                    ' Cancel if not in "cdolive.com", "slipstick.com", "outlookmvp.com"
                    If Not SendMail Then Cancel = True
                    MsgBox "The entered email address(s) are not aliged to you" & vbNewLine & "Please add the domain name in the code"
                  'End If
                'End If
                End If
            Next
            Last:
            End If
            End If
            End If
            End Sub



            Function GetDomain(emailAddress As String) As String

                Dim arr As Variant

                arr = Split(emailAddress, "@")

                GetDomain = Left(arr(1), InStrRev(arr(1), ".") - 1)

            End Function

            Function SubjectContainsEmailDomain(subject As String, email As String) As Boolean

                Dim domain As String
                domain = GetDomain(email)
                Dim index As Integer


                SubjectContainsEmailDomain = InStr(LCase(subject), LCase(domain))


            End Function
```